# Change color of my bar chart?

Tags: javascript

so I have made a javascript function where I generate a bar chart. Everything works fine but I want to change colors of the bars. Now every bar is green but what I want is that if the data is below 0 then the bar has to change into red.

```
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/data.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET'
            }).done(function(data) {
                var plotData = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    plotData.push([data[i].Datum, parseInt(data[i].Gevoel)]); 

                var bar_data = {
                        data: plotData,
                        color: "green"      
                };

                $.plot("#bar-chart", [bar_data], {
                    grid: {
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
                        tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
                    },
                    series: {
                        bars: {
                            show: true,
                            barWidth: 0.5,
                            align: "center"
                        }
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        mode: "categories",
                        tickLength: 0
                    }
                });
            /* END BAR CHART */
        }); 
    });
```

[image]

So 1 and 2 has to change to the color red.

Comment: Have you tried any if statements regarding if the data: is < 0){color:red}else{color:green} ?

Comment: yes I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that "Datum" is your X-axis value and "Geveol" is your y-axis. I haven't tested the code but it should work.

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data) {
            var plotData = [];
            var bar_data = {
                    data: [],
                    color: []      
                };
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                bar_data.data.push([[data[i].Datum, parseInt(data[i].Gevoel)]]); 
                if(parseInt(data[i].Gevoel) > 0)
                   bar_data.color.push("green");
                else
                   bar_data.color.push("red");
            }
            $.plot("#bar-chart", [bar_data], {
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
                    tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
                },
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.5,
                        align: "center"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0
                }
            });
        /* END BAR CHART */
    }); 
});
```

---

## EDIT

I updated the code above. Sorry, made some obvious mistakes in the first version and am a bit rusty with Jquery Flot.
To make each bar a separate series it needs to be wrapped in double arrays. Then the color property can be an array of equal length, giving the color for each bar

---

## EDIT 2

Here is a jsfiddle using data from the Flot example which I have working with multiple colors. I'm not sure what's not working for you with my sample code but this should help: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/VztHb/2/)

Comment: Now it doesn't draw my chart

Comment: Something is still wrong. Now it draws the chart only the bars are missing